# WPF Stop Scrollviewer Scroilling?

Tags: wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

i search for a way to stop the scrolling in a scrollviewer temporary and the Content inside is available.

Different ways i have tried, the ScrollViewer Scroll also with non Visible ScrollBars the property ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll is only a difference for the kind of Scrolling.

Any other ideas to Stop the Scrolling?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting scroll bar visibility to ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

</ScrollViewer>
```